# Unable to accept SSL certificate (k9mail)

Tags: certificates, https, k9-mail

I am setting up k9mail on a 4.2 device (rooted Sony Xperia Mini Pro with stock ROM and crap removed) and it complains about the IMAP SSL certificate not being valid.

This happens with both a self-signed certificate, and also on a different IMAP server with Comodo-signed certificate (which is normally accepted by browsers and other mail clients).

> Unrecognized Certificate
>
> The server presented an invalid SSL certificate. Sometimes, this is
>   because of server misconfiguration. Sometimes it is because someone is
>   trying to atta you or your mail server. If you you're not sure what to
>   do, click Reject and contact the folks who manage your mail server.
>
> (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.) Certificate chain[0]:
>
> ...

Clicking "Accept Key", however, make the same dialogue come up again and again in a loop.

What is the problem? Can it be that k9mail is unable to add the key to the cert store? How to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by re-installing k9mail from scratch (the previous install, which exhibited the error, was from installed using Titanium Backup, from a backup on another phone).